# Bypass client certificate selection on POST request in dart (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

I'm trying to post data to server (API) which asks for (optional) client certificate.

I'm creating http POST request with http package for dart (https://pub.dev/packages/http).

```
  var uriResponse = await client
      .post(
          'https://myApiUrl',
          headers: headers,
          body: json.encode(dataToPost))
      .then((res) {
    ...success code... 
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
```

I'm getting (at .post call line):

`Exception has occurred.  ClientException ()`

Exception message is empty.

Changing the server configuration so that it no longer requires a client certificate fixes the problem.

How can I bypass client certificate prompt?